# react-plotly.js - Chloropleth map not displaying

Tags: reactjs, plotly.js

I am trying to convert an existing Plot.ly React component to consume different data; however, the raw data the existing component is consuming is difficult to trace. I have come this far, replacing the ~opaque data functions from the original plot with test "data" for three countries:

```
      <Plot
        data={[
          {
            type: 'choropleth',
            locationmode: 'country names',
            locations: ['MEXICO', 'CANADA', 'EL SALVADOR'],
            z: [1, 2, 3],
            text: ['MEXICO', 'CANADA', 'EL SALVADOR'],
            autocolorscale: true,
          },
        ]}
        layout={{
          paper_bgcolor: '#f7e4ca',
          hoverlabel: {
            bordercolor: '#f7e4ca',
          },
          geo: {
            scope: 'world',
            projection: {
              type: 'robinson',
            },
          },
        }}
        style={{ width: '100%', fontWeight: '900' }}
      />
```

This displays a chloropleth component with a gradient representing the z-axis; however, no world map appears. Am I representing the data for `locations` and `z` here in a format that Plotly does not accept? How can I pass raw data into a React-Plotly.js chloropleth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the people working with this component were doing to make it visible before, but one thing that can make it visible is, under `layout`, setting `width` and `height` properties. You can set them to numbers. This works:

```
      <Plot
        data={[
          {
            type: 'choropleth',
            locationmode: 'country names',
            locations: ['MEXICO', 'CANADA', 'EL SALVADOR'],
            z: [1, 2, 3],
            text: ['MEXICO', 'CANADA', 'EL SALVADOR'],
            autocolorscale: true,
          },
        ]}
        layout={{
          paper_bgcolor: '#f7e4ca',
          hoverlabel: {
            bordercolor: '#f7e4ca',
          },
          geo: {
            scope: 'world',
            projection: {
              type: 'robinson',
            },
          },
          height: 400,
          width: 400,
        }}
        style={{ width: '100%', fontWeight: '900' }}
      />
```